# WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 is giving false error "Unexpected error sending message back "

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a Production environment running on WSO2 ESB 4.9.0. I am facing a strange errors. This type error appears randomly on different components with after every 10 seconds or 15 seconds.

**Error Message 1:**

```
 Unexpected error sending message back
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.handleException(Axis2Sender.java:247)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:215)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:444)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:102)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:30)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SwitchCase.mediate(SwitchCase.java:66)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:123)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:297)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:247)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:610)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**Error Message 2:**

```
Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:610)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:444)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:102)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:30)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SwitchCase.mediate(SwitchCase.java:66)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:123)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:297)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:247)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**Problem:**

The main problem is that in actual all the messages are being sent and responses are received on back-end. I have double checked it from all the parties, both the consuming and producing end. No message is dropped. But in ESB logs these messages are appearing very frequently. And Is there any possibility that ESB is giving us error messages as false negative because In real the messages are sent and received perfectly. IF so, why ESB is thinking that responses are not being sent?

Comment: it would be helpful to provide the proxy or sequence files (if possible, I understand it's not always simple to provide) or even debug level logs (Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException, but you need the stacktrace of the NullPointerException itself)

Comment: Still check - are all responses properly received by all parties? (even the client, not just backend), this exception reminds be of an issue, when the body is not an XML (invalid XML or not the declared message type) and Axis framework fails to serialize the message to the output stream. Indeed you should provide the full stacktrace to get any reasonable answer :)

Comment: When u receive responses, verify whether content type and type of responses as expected. It will be really needed. This issue can be seen when response comes as unexpected type.